# How to make search query like Youtube?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a search query like Youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=new+york

here is the address and you can see that the last words are the search text.

whatever you type on search query text it shows youtube result.

Is this form get action?

or How can I build with PHP(Codeigniter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually has nothing to do with the underlying server side language. Basic HTML can give you that result:

```
<form action="//yoursite.com/results" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search_query" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```